# One Button To Toggle Form's BackGround Color

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a novice in C# WindowForm projects, and I am facing some issues on how to toggle 'one button' into changing between 2 backcolors in C# WindowForm.

In order to toggle 'one button', I am required to use IF function in this assignment. However, my problem is that I do not know how to transition from color1 to 2 by pressing the button when running the code, I somewhat know the syntax structure of IF and else.

Could anyone help please?

```
namespace draft
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      bool btnclick = true;
      if (btnclick == true)
      {
        BackColor = Color.Purple;
        return;
      }
      if (btnclick == false)
      {
        BackColor = Color.Green;
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are declaring `btnclick` on click event and setting it to true, it will be true every time and only if block will be executed. Check current background color and change it.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackColor == Color.Purple)
        {
            BackColor = Color.Green;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            BackColor = Color.Purple;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, it tells me the following: https://i.imgur.com/XrvSNlU.png

Comment: It should be BackColor == Color.Purple double == is for comparision and = is for assignment.

Comment: My goodness, thank you so much sir. What if I wanted to toggle these two colors infinitely (non-stop)? what would I do in this case

Comment: You can use a timer with time interval of 1 sec or what ever you want. Write above logic on tick event.

Comment: Thank you once again!, I was overcomplicating it for nothing.

Comment: @SaileshBabuDoppalapudi - Why did you keep the `return;` in the `if`/`else`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackColor = BackColor == Color.Purple ? Color.Green : Color.Purple;
}
```

Comment: Nice! It does look very brief, but I cannot understand it, why did you equalize BackColor to BackColor and then to Purple with a question mark along with Color.Green: Color.Purple;? What if we revolve the button by toggling it into 3 colors: the default by windowform, green and purple?

Comment: @Oso - It's not "equalizing" (assigning) `BackColor` to `BackColor`. This is the ternary operation. It looks like `condition ? true : false`. So it's checking if `BackColor == Color.Purple` and if that's true it returns `Color.Green`, but if it is false it returns `Color.Purple`.

Comment: @Oso - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator